# Loading security for some specific tests only

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to have some integration tests that exercise some business controllers, and other tests that exercise the security configuration.

So I have the business controllers tests extend a `BaseTest` class and the security configuration tests extend a `SecurityBaseTest` class.

I want to load the security configuration only for the tests that exercise it, and not for the business controllers tests as these should only exercise the controllers and not the security configuration.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfiguration.class, WebConfiguration.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public abstract class BaseTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
        httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    }

}

@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class, WebConfiguration.class })
public abstract class SecurityBaseTest extends BaseTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        super.setup();
        userFixtureService.addUserFixture();

        addTokenToRequestHeader(httpHeaders, UserFixtureService.USER_EMAIL);
    }

    private void addTokenToRequestHeader(HttpHeaders headers, String username) {
        tokenAuthenticationService.addTokenToResponseHeader(headers, username);
    }

}
```

When running the business controllers tests using the command `mvn clean install -Denv="test" -Ddb="h2" -Dtest=UserControllerTest -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE"` then the debugger shows that the security configuration is rightfully not being loaded.

But the `testCrudOperations` method fails as it returns a `403` status and not the `201` as expected. And the debugger shows that the `UserController` controller endpoint is not being hit at all.

```
public class UserControllerTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void testCrudOperations() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc
                .perform(post(RESTConstants.SLASH + UserDomainConstants.USERS)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .headers(httpHeaders)
                .content(jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(userResource0)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname").value(userResource0.getFirstname()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastname").value(userResource0.getLastname()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value(userResource0.getEmail()))
                .andExpect(header().string("Location", Matchers.containsString("/users/"))).andReturn();
        UserResource retrievedUserResource = deserializeResource(mvcResult, UserResource.class);
        assertThatUserResource(retrievedUserResource).hasEmail(userResource0.getEmail());
        assertThatUserResource(retrievedUserResource)
                .hasRole(retrievedUserResource.getUserRoles().iterator().next().getRole());
        userResource0.setResourceId(retrievedUserResource.getResourceId());
    }
}
```

When running the security configuration tests using the command `mvn clean install -Denv="test" -Ddb="h2" -Dtest=UserAuthenticationTest -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE"`  then the debugger shows that the security configuration is rightfully being loaded.

But the `testUnsecuredResourceGrantsAccess` method fails, with the error `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy' available` message.

```
public class UserAuthenticationTest extends SecurityBaseTest {
    @Test
    public void testUnsecuredResourceGrantsAccess() throws Exception {
            this.mockMvc.perform(
                post(RESTConstants.SLASH + UserDomainConstants.USERS + RESTConstants.SLASH + UserDomainConstants.LOGIN)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            )
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andReturn();
    }
}
```

The security configuration is:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter = new AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/login", RequestMethod.POST.name()));
        authenticationFromCredentialsFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationFromCredentialsFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter = new AuthenticationFromTokenFilter(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/login")));
        authenticationFromTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationFromTokenFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter> disableAutoRegistration(final AuthenticationFromTokenFilter filter) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter>(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .logout().disable();

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(simpleCORSFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

        http
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationFromTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/error").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/users/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(UserDomainConstants.ROLE_ADMIN)
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Comment: I could solve the `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy' available` issue by removing the `(debug = true)` from the `@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)` annotation.

Comment: I could also solve the `403` status response by adding a security configuration used by the non-secured tests only. This configuration contains the following statements `http.cors();

  http
  .csrf().disable()
  .formLogin().disable()
  .httpBasic().disable()
  .logout().disable();

  http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

  http.addFilterBefore(simpleCORSFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);`